# FLASK - How to configure port using app.config['PORT']?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask

So I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login-es) tutorial on-line and built a site that works perfectly on my local network. Now I'm trying to deploy it at Google's App Engine and I'm encountering an error.
Basically I don't know how to change the port my flask app is running on (without using app.run() ).

I just practially copy-pasted the code from the tutorial and adjusted it a bit, so I'm not sure how to set th eport withing the code. And since the tutorial never used any `app.run(port=8080)` and the page works, I'm not sure I want to introduce that slice of code. However, the code does use app.config[] to set the SECRET_KEY for example. And I've tried using the same method to set the PORT, but it just doesn't work. How can do this??

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

#init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['PORT'] = 8080
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = b'someweirdshit'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

    db.init_app(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .models import User

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))

    #blueprint for auth routes in our app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    #blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

The code above is just one of the scripts used in my Flask App. I know it is being executed since the app succesfully connects and uses the *db.sqlite* databased configured in line 13. But line 11 (where I try to configure the port) just doesn't seem to work.
[image: Command Line Screenshot where Flask App is seen running on port 5000 and not 8080]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is nothing wrong with using `app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=<PORT_NUMBER>, debug=True)`. If you go that route, then you just end up doing `python main.py` from the project folder to run your App.
2. If you still don't want to use `app.run`, then you should use `FLASK_RUN_PORT` to specify your port number (see [Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/cli/#setting-command-options))

```
    $ export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
    $ flask run
```

3. If you don't want to deal with the commands `python main.py` or `flask run`, then you can use a GAE GUI (e.g ours - https://nocommandline.com) to manage your code (i.e. run it locally and deploy it to production). With a GUI, you click a button to run your file locally and another button to deploy to production.  If your code is written in `Python2`, you don't have to include a port number in the code. You just specify the port number on the GUI UI and `GCloud's dev_appserver.py` (which the GUI uses behind the scene) will take care of attaching the port number. If it's Python3, then you'll have to include code like

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=<PORT_NUMBER>, debug=True)
```